# Orca yearly graph is not showing correct results

Tags: solaris, performance-monitoring, solaris-10

We are using Orca for performance monitoring on a number of solaris servers. We've got plots for hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly.

However, the yearly plot is displaying hour times on the x-axis, which is clearly incorrect.

Is there a way to fix this?

Sample yearly graph: [image: Sample Yearly graph]

[Link to orcallator.cfg](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_V30PzM0H4D_0.py)

Comment: Can you show your orcallator configuration file?

Comment: And show a copy of a bad yearly plot.

Comment: added that too.